# Laravel 5.3 - Missing "value" attribute in query builder

Tags: datatables, laravel-5.3

I am new to Laravel and Yajra datatable. I have developed a web application (In windows XAMPP) and everything works perfectly until I upload my project in shared hosting (UNIX) recently, the datatable unable to load the view and throwing the error message.

The error message I get is:

> ErrorException in Request.php line 38:
>   Undefined index: value
>   in Request.php line 38
>   at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Undefined index: value', '/home/posgb/public_html/boatMain/vendor/yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle/src/Request.php', '38', array()) in Request.php line 38

I have compared DD results of my query builder output in both my machine and server and found that the "value" attribute was missing from the "search" array.

My query:

```
$query = DB::table('item_subcat')
                ->leftJoin('item_customized', 'item_subcat.subcatID', '=', 'item_customized.subcatID')
                ->join('item_cat', 'item_subcat.itemCatID', '=', 'item_cat.itemCatID')
                ->select(array('item_subcat.subcatID', 'item_subcat.itemCode', 'item_subcat.itemName', 'item_cat.itemCatName', 'item_customized.customize_name', DB::raw('IF(item_subcat.is_categorize = "0", item_subcat.itemPrice, item_customized.price) AS ITEMPRICE'), 'item_subcat.is_activate', 'item_customized.itemCustomID'));
dd($query);
```

**DD results in my pc:**

```
                #parameters: array:7 [
                  "draw" => "1"
                  "columns" => array:7 [
                    0 => array:5 [ …5]
                    1 => array:5 [ …5]
                    2 => array:5 [ …5]
                    3 => array:5 [ …5]
                    4 => array:5 [ …5]
                    5 => array:5 [ …5]
                    6 => array:5 [ …5]
                  ]
                  "order" => array:1 [
                    0 => array:2 [ …2]
                  ]
                  "start" => "0"
                  "length" => "10"
                  "search" => array:2 [
                    "value" => ""  /*This is the missing value */
                    "regex" => "false"
                  ]
                  "branch" => "ALL"
                ]
              }
```

**DD result in my server:**

```
 +request: ParameterBag {#41
                #parameters: array:7 [
                  "draw" => "1"
                  "columns" => array:7 [
                    0 => array:5 [ …5]
                    1 => array:5 [ …5]
                    2 => array:5 [ …5]
                    3 => array:5 [ …5]
                    4 => array:5 [ …5]
                    5 => array:5 [ …5]
                    6 => array:5 [ …5]
                  ]
                  "order" => array:1 [
                    0 => array:2 [ …2]
                  ]
                  "start" => "0"
                  "length" => "10"
                  "search" => array:1 [
                    "regex" => "false"
                  ]
                  "branch" => "ALL"
                ]
              }
```

Please can advise me where should I look into the missing "value" in array, as it cause me unable to generate the datatable. TYVM for those spent times to look at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was due to PHP.ini settings in my server which disallow null value in GET and POST request by default.